# Distinct and Populate

Tags: mongoose

Is it possible something like this in Mongoose?

```
User
    .findById(req.user)
    .populate({
        path: "x"})
    .populate({
        path: "messages",
        match: { to: req.user},
        select: "from date message"
        **distinct: "from"**
    })

    .exec (function(err, doc) {
    }
```

If not, how could I get only messages with not repeated "from" in doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
User
    .findById(req.user)
    .populate({
        path: "x"
    })
    .populate({
        path: "messages",
        match: { to: req.user},
        select: "from date message"
    })
    .exec (function(err, doc) {

      Message.distinct("from",doc.messages,function(err, doc) {
      })
```

Comment: This forces me to redo my query. Were you able to chain this inside the populate itself?